# SQL table viewing page created dynamically?

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, user-interface

I have a SQL database for a dynamically generated form that users submit.
It is normalized and I have one normal table(user_data) and two sub-tables(activities, awards) that are linked to the normal table.
I was thinking about making a page where the normal table's data is displayed like

```
Name Date activityID awardID formID description
foo  5/4  23251      23101   4343   "blah blah"
```

and you would click on the activity id or award id number given to open a popup window which would show the data linked to that ID in the activity or award table. like

```
activityID formID activityDescription activityDate
23251      4343   "bladhsh baldshh"   5/4
```

I also would need to make it so that it shows the data in paginated sections, instead of showing the whole thing at once...

I am a beginner-intermediate html, Javascript, and PHP coder. I already made a dynamically generated html/Javascript form and a PHP that processes all the data submitted, and I created a normalized database. I'm trying to figure out how people usually do this kind of task, and what scripting language they use. I heard you need to use AJAX and jQuery, but I am unfamiliar with either of those languages. Is it hard to learn, and how exactly do they work?

Comment: You can do that using PHP.  Just make the row link to a .php file that takes an `awardid` as a parameter

Comment: Ah, but I wanted to make the page a little bit neater, and if I do it with PHP, it'll be pretty ugly, and you will have to load a new page every time you change the page whereas if i use some sort of javascript-related language like jquery, it can be done asynchronously so you dont have to refresh the page or go to a new page.

Comment: That's true, but AJAX/JavaScript is a lot more work, and a lot harder to maintain.  You can Google for [ajax php tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+php+tutorial) to find many [good results](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).

Comment: ah.... hmm well then I think I will make a php version first for now, and maybe when I become a little bit more proficient, I'll try to remake it in AJAX, but i will check out the tutorial! please post an answer so i can +rep you!

Comment: Good choice.  I'll post the comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using PHP. Just make the row link to a .php file that takes an awardid as a parameter.

AJAX/JavaScript is a lot more work, and a lot harder to maintain.  You can Google for [ajax php tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+php+tutorial) to find many [good results](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).